# Setting variable based on IF - Batch Scripting

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a script that I'm working on that I'm pretty stuck on... It may be just a syntax error but I'm not sure.

The script checks how old each file is that is hardcoded in the script (This script is a subscript that is being generated by another). The checkage2.bat script outputs an %AGE% variable if file is over 20 minutes old the AGE=1 otherwise AGE=0

```
SET FILEPATH="C:\PathToFile\Filename1.slf"  
CALL C:\PathToScript\checkage2.bat %FILEPATH%  
IF %AGE% EQU 1 OUTPUT=%OUTPUT% %FILEPATH%

SET FILEPATH="C:\PathToFile\Filename2.slf"  
CALL C:\PathToScript\checkage2.bat %FILEPATH%  
IF %AGE% EQU 1 OUTPUT=%OUTPUT% %FILEPATH%

SET FILEPATH="C:\PathToFile\Filename3.slf"  
CALL C:\PathToScript\checkage2.bat %FILEPATH%  
IF %AGE% EQU 1 OUTPUT=%OUTPUT% %FILEPATH%
IF (%OUTPUT%) == () GOTO OK

ECHO CRITICAL: %OUTPUT%
PAUSE

:OK
ECHO OK: All files within 20 minute time range 
PAUSE
```

I'm trying to output a full list of all files that are over 20 minutes old but I can't seem to get it right! Any help will be really appreciated, thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IF %AGE% EQU 1 OUTPUT=%OUTPUT% %FILEPATH%
```

Maybe if you were to `SET OUTPUT=...`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @KickButtowski Dingo's kidneys! The response I've made is obvious - but if you really need it to be explicit (this is known as "spoonfeeding") then `IF %AGE% EQU 1 OUTPUT=%OUTPUT% %FILEPATH%` should be `IF %AGE% EQU 1 SET OUTPUT=%OUTPUT% %FILEPATH%` throughout because in batch, to `set` a variable you need to use the `set` keyword, not simply use the required expression, as MCND posted a whole minute later.

Comment: Thanks Magoo, your first answer was more than enough :) thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the missing `SET` commands in variable assignment and the `IF` condition that will fail when there are spaces between the elements.

```
SET "OUTPUT="

SET FILEPATH="C:\PathToFile\Filename1.slf"
CALL C:\PathToScript\checkage2.bat %FILEPATH%
IF %AGE% EQU 1 SET OUTPUT=%OUTPUT% %FILEPATH%

SET FILEPATH="C:\PathToFile\Filename2.slf"
CALL C:\PathToScript\checkage2.bat %FILEPATH%
IF %AGE% EQU 1 SET OUTPUT=%OUTPUT% %FILEPATH%

SET FILEPATH="C:\PathToFile\Filename3.slf"
CALL C:\PathToScript\checkage2.bat %FILEPATH%
IF %AGE% EQU 1 SET OUTPUT=%OUTPUT% %FILEPATH% 

IF DEFINED OUTPUT (
    ECHO CRITICAL: %OUTPUT% 
) ELSE (
    ECHO OK: All files within 20 minute time range
)
PAUSE
```